# Поиск по ID в приложений Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, router, blade

Может я сейчас не правильно вырожусь поправьте пожалуйста. Речь идет о приложении **Laravel**
У меня есть код

```
<input type="text" class="form-control " name="access_code" id="access_cool"  required="required" autofocus=""  placeholder="{{ __('service::install.access_cool') }}" >
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно искать по **ID** (если это конечно возможно) я хочу найти место за которое отвечает **id="access_cool"** или где расположен **{{ __('service::install.access_cool') }}** Куда-то же от суда запросы уходят, а куда не знаю

И можно еще по пути узнать, почему при **APP_DEBUG="true"** включений, он не включается?

Comment: "от суда" - в прокуратуру, например.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на первый вопрос

Поискать расположение `id="access_cool"` можно в 2-х местах:

1. В атрибуте `action=""` расположенном выше в теге `<form>`. Там вы увидите роут, а по роуту уже можно увидеть контроллер в котором и используется данное поле.
2. Если данные отправляются по ajax - то ищите либо ниже по какому url отправляется запрос, либо в прикреплённом js файле к этому blaid файлу.

На второй же вопрос
Дело может быть в кэше.

Выполни: `php artisan optimize:clear`